# How to serialize an ArrayList of custom type?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I have a class with this member:

```
var wpts : ArrayList<Location>
```

I've also created a custom serializer:

```
object LocationSerializer: KSerializer<Location>{
        override val descriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("Location") {
            element<Double>("lat")
            element<Double>("lon")
        }

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Location = decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var lat = -1.0
            var lon = -1.0
            while (true) {
                when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> lat = decodeDoubleElement(descriptor, 0)
                    1 -> lon = decodeDoubleElement(descriptor, 1)
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> error("Unexpected index: $index")
                }
            }
            require(lat in -90.0..90.0 && lon in -180.0..180.0)
            val l = Location("")
            l.latitude = lat
            l.longitude = lon
            return l
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Location) = encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeDoubleElement(descriptor, 0, (value.latitude))
            encodeDoubleElement(descriptor, 1, (value.longitude))
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to define the serializer to the *wpts* member and adding this annotation does not work:

```
@Serializable(with = Serializers.Companion.LocationSerializer::class)
```

I keep getting this error:

> Serializer has not been found for type 'Location'.

Comment: I think you can use GSON for this usecase.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Gson is outdated, it's not really maintained anymore and also doesn't work well with Kotlin nullability guarantees in general. I would not advise using it.

Comment: @Joffrey who told you that GSON is t's not really maintained?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about `android.location.Location`, I only see the following options:

1. Create your own serializable Location class and use that instead:

   ```
   @Serializable(with = MyLocationSerializer::class)
   class MyLocation(provider: String): Location(provider)
   ```

   and

   ```
   var wpts : ArrayList<MyLocation>
   ```
2. Create a custom serializer for `ArrayList<Location>`.
3. Use Gson or a different serialization library.